# Python Logging leaving file empty

Tags: python-3.x, python-logging

I know there are a lot of questions related to this but I haven't found the one that applies to my case.

I'm running a script (Python 3.7.0) on Windows that should log some events, but it is only creating the empty file log_minera.log.

Logging level seems to be ok, same as writting mode, handler connected to logger... I suspect closing the window just kills unflushed streams so never get written, but adding the line to flush doesn't work either hitting ENTER or closing. Help please!

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
handler = logging.FileHandler('log_minera.log', mode='w')
formatter = logging.Formatter('* %(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
logger.addHandler(handler)

while True:
    logger.info('info to be logged')
    # code...
    logger.error('other info related to errors')
    # more code

    #logger.handlers[0].flush() <- does nothing
    answer = input('Press ENTER to repeat or close the window to exit.')
```

Comment: I tried your code with this results in the logger:
* 2019-03-25 10:11:31,362 - __main__ - ERROR - other info related to errors
* 2019-03-25 10:11:34,251 - __main__ - ERROR - other info related to errors can you tell me more about your enviroment, have you checked the folder where yout code is at?

Comment: The folder contains some input files to be processed and the script packed in an exe file which works perfectly well besides logging. As I said, the file is created at the same folder but keeps empty during execution and remains that way after closed. Also my user is the owner of the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You do not set the level of your custom logger. Therefore, it has the same level as the parent logger, in your case, probably the root logger.

I tried your code and in my setup, `logger` has a level `WARNING`. It means that `"info to be logged"` will not get logged inside the file.

On your setup, it could be that you set your root logger level to something greater than `ERROR`, maybe `CRITICAL`, creating your `logger` with that level. In that case, nothing under `logger.critical` would be printed.

Either set your root logger level to `INFO` or set the `logger` level to `INFO` explicitely, like this:

```py
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)  # <- HERE
```